# set a binary value in a char column in DB2 12 using a PreparedStatement in jdbc

Tags: jdbc, binary, char, db2, prepared-statement

I need to update a CHAR column in a table in DB2 12 (with driver 4.25.21).
I always use a PreparedStatement to avoid sql injection.
Sometimes I need to send a binary value to the database.

If using Oracle, you can simply use `setBytes(byte[])`, but DB2 gives me an error:

> SQLCODE=-301, SQLSTATE=42895: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: THE VALUE OF INPUT VARIABLE OR ARGUMENT NUMBER 1 CANNOT BE USED AS SPECIFIED BECAUSE OF ITS DATA TYPE. SQLCODE=-301, SQLSTATE=42895, DRIVER=4.25.21

.

I have tried a prepared like  `... set column=to_char(?) ...` then using `setBytes()` but then i get

> SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: A STATEMENT STRING TO BE PREPARED CONTAINS AN INVALID USE OF PARAMETER MARKERS. SQLCODE=-418, SQLSTATE=42610, DRIVER=4.25.21

.

I know a could build a String in EBCDIC in Java, but i would prefer have the conversion made by the database

How could I do it?

Comment: what is the column data type? Is this Db2 for z/OS? What is a sample value you want to set?

Comment: The column data type is CHAR
Yes, it is Db2 for z/OS
The value could be any at all

Comment: The value could be any binary with the apropiate size

Comment: I forgot to say that it is acceptable to send de value in hexadecimal format

Comment: You may try `set column=cast(? as varchar(XXX) for bit data)`. Set `XXX` in bytes accordingly to the maximum input length of your value.

Comment: Using "cast(? as varchar(XXX) for bit data)" I got the same error: -301

Comment: sorry: I had said it was DB2 11 but it is DB2 12

Comment: is the CCSID of the target column in Db2-for-Z/OS valued at 1208 unicode? OR is the CCSID something different, ask your Z DBA if you do not know.

Comment: The CCSID is not 1208. (It is 0)